# How to inherit multiple partial classes when all have the same base class (including the new class)?

Tags: c#, oop

So I'm not very good with OOP, and am a little stumped. If I already have classes that are FruitHandlers from the FruitHandler library that look something like this:

```
public partial class AppleCleaner : FruitHandler {

    public AppleCleaner(int fruitSize) {
        CleanApple(fruitSize);
    }

    void CleanApple(int size) {
        //code to clean an apple;
    }
}

public partial class PearCleaner : FruitHandler {

    public PearCleaner(int fruitSize) {
        CleanPear(fruitSize);
    }

    void CleanPear(int size) {
        //code to clean a pear;
    }
}

public partial class BananaCleaner : FruitHandler {

    public BananaCleaner(int fruitSize) {
        CleanBanana(fruitSize);
    }

    void CleanBanana(int size) {
        //code to clean a banana;
    }
}
```

and I want to make a class that also has the base class FruitHandler, but is capable of using CleanApple, CleanPear, or CleanBanana that looks something like this:

```
public partial class FruitEater : FruitHandler {

    public FruitEater(Fruit fruit) {
        if (fruit.Name == "Apple") {
            CleanApple(fruit.size);
        } else if (fruit.Name == "Pear") {
            CleanPear(fruit.size);
        } else if (fruit.Name == "Banana") {
            CleanBanana(fruit.size);
        }

        EatFruit(fruit);
    }

    void EatFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        // eat it;
    }
}
```

I can refactor these pretty liberally, but the caveat is that the base class for all of them **must** be a FruitHandler (because in real life these are all Forms and the base class must be Form).

Comment: Add an abstract method `Clean()` to your FruitHandler class and implement it in each of your derived classes.

Comment: Also `partial` just means that your class is declared in more than one location... it's not an inheritance related keyword. It doesn't look like you have presented any requirement for using `partial`.

Comment: `CleanApple` is an instance method, you must call it on an instance of `AppleCleaner`. Where is your instance? I would suggest your example is too far from your problem (`Form` is different) to get helpful answers.

Comment: I don't think your structure really makes sense. Why is a `AppleCleaner` a `Sink`? Why is `FruitEater` a `Sink`?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli To the end of the question... "because in real life these are all Forms and the base class must be Form"

Comment: Let me edit the example to be a little more accurate to the actual problem

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That doesn't mean it makes sense...

Comment: Ok changed Sink to be FruitHandler and specified that that's from a library. Let me know if I can make it more clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Don't make all of the subclasses have specialized `Clean()` methods. Do like @GlorinOakenfoot suggested and make an abstract `Clean()` method in `FruitHandler`. Then your `FruitEater` method can just do `fruit.Clean()`.

Comment: How could I do that if FruitHandler is from a library, so the best I can do is see the metadata of that class?

Comment: I'd have to have some kind of abstract class that inherits from FruitHandler that defines Clean(), then have all of the cleaners implement that guy?

Comment: Add an "in-between" class which notes your abstract requirements. So say, CleanerBase inherits from FruitHandler, and declares abstract Clean(). Then all of your classes could derive from CleanerBase.

Comment: Does Clean modify the state of class it is implemented in?

Comment: Yes it does. It's almost as if size is a global variable for each class, and after cleaning the size is reduced by the weight of the dirt. Sorry the example is so abstract and not perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
interface IFruitCleaner {
    void Clean(int size)
}

public partial class AppleCleaner : FruitHandler, IFruitCleaner {

    public AppleCleaner(int fruitSize) {
        Clean(fruitSize);
    }

    void Clean(int size) {
        //code to clean an apple;
    }
}


public partial class FruitEater : FruitHandler {

    public FruitEater(Fruit fruit, IFruitCleaner cleaner) {
        cleaner.Clean(fruit.size);
        EatFruit(fruit);
    }

    void EatFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        // eat it;
    }
}
```

Seems like you would want to pass the fruit to `AppleCleaner` as opposed to just the size, but I've left it as you have it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use interfaces for this. Unless each class is going to execute code in their base class (which isn't the case here), you should use an interface to define the common methods across the classes:

```
public interface IFruit {
    void Clean(int Size);
}

public partial class AppleCleaner : IFruit, FruitHandler {

    public AppleCleaner(int fruitSize) {
        Clean(fruitSize);
    }

    void Clean(int size) {
        //code to clean an apple;
    }
}

public partial class PearCleaner : IFruit, FruitHandler {

    public PearCleaner(int fruitSize) {
        Clean(fruitSize);
    }

    void Clean(int size) {
        //code to clean a pear;
    }
}

public partial class BananaCleaner : IFruit, FruitHandler {

    public BananaCleaner(int fruitSize) {
        Clean(fruitSize);
    }

    void Clean(int size) {
        //code to clean a banana;
    }
}
```

This also simplifies your `FruitEater` class quite a bit:

```
public partial class FruitEater : FruitHandler {

    public FruitEater(IFruit fruit, int size) {
        fruit.Clean(size);
        EatFruit(fruit);
    }

    void EatFruit(IFruit fruit) {
        // eat it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd put clean in the base class, but as you said it was a Form in real world example, you could use an interface.

```
public interface IFruitCleaner  {
   void Clean(int size);
}

public partial class AppleCleaner : FruitHandler, IFruitCleaner
{

    public AppleCleaner(int fruitSize)
    {
        Clean(fruitSize);
    }

    void Clean(int size)
    {
        //code to clean an apple;
    }
}

public partial class PearCleaner : FruitHandler, IFruitCleaner
{

    public PearCleaner(int fruitSize)
    {
        Clean(fruitSize);
    }

    void Clean(int size)
    {
        //code to clean a pear;
    }
}


public partial class BananaCleaner : FruitHandler, IFruitCleaner
{

    public BananaCleaner(int fruitSize)
    {
        Clean(fruitSize);
    }

    void Clean(int size)
    {
        //code to clean a banana;
    }
}
```